# Firebase Analytics event logging error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I use Firebase Analytics and my app logs some events with this code:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "SOME_ID")
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "SOME_TYPE");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

And it seem to work well most of the time. In logcat I have something like this:

```
Logging event (FE): select_content, Bundle[{_o=app, content_type=SOME_TYPE, item_id=SOME_ID}]
```

But for some events I receive

```
Logging event (FE): select_content, Bundle[{_o=app, _ev=item_id, _err=4, content_type=SOME_TYPE}]
```

> Apparently, _err=4 is some kind of error code. What does it mean?

In that cases with error my `item_id` was a pretty long string (20-30 symbols). Maybe there is a limitation on the length of the `item_id`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

According to [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param):

> Param names can be up to 40 characters long, may only contain
>   alphanumeric characters and underscores ("_"), and must start with an
>   alphabetic character. Param values can be up to 100 characters long.

So, they have length constraints on both Key and Value.

Key: 40 characters long

Value: 100 characters long

Comment: Thanks for replay.

Comment: How does Google expect developers to normalize all event values to less than 36 chars??

Comment: Not related to error code 4, but for error code 7 ("User property value is too long"): I was stripping the values of my user properties to 40 characters, but it turns out the actual limit is 36 characters as @OdedRegev mentioned. I tried shortening the property keys, but that had no effect.

Comment: If this is used for the Firebase+GTM SDK - you can use longer values for now

Answer (score 17):

You are logging event with a parameter that exceeds the maximum value limit. There was accompanying FA/Error log message with more details that you probably missed.

Here is the list of the Firebase Analytics error codes:
1 - Invalid Firebase project id.
2 - Event name is invalid (empty, too long, invalid characters).
3 - Event parameter name is invalid (empty, too long, invalid characters).
4 - Event parameter value is too long.
5 - Event has more than 25 parameters.
6 - User property name is invalid (empty, too long, invalid characters).
7 - User property value is too long.
8 - App Instance logs more than 500 unique event types.
9 - App Instance sets more than 25 unique user properties.
10 - App Instance exceeds conversion event limit in a single day.
13 - Event name is reserved.
14 - Event parameter name is reserved.
15 - User property name is reserved.
11, 12, 16 - Internal error.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, They have a restriction on the length of the item_id. In my case as well while I was integrating it with my app, got the same errors when my item_id was long.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to error code values in [Official Google Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/errors). It clearly states that error 4 means "Event parameter value is too long". Hope this helps someone with different error code too.