# Firebase logging error on automatic events

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am logging some custom events on Firebase Analytics, but some errors keep getting logged for automatic events (such as `screen_view`) along with the custom events, whether I call them explicitly or not. When I log regular custom events (a button click, for example), I can see them on DebugView without any errors.

I have validated the rules for names (maximum of 36 chars for event key, maximum of 100 for value) as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38473867/5120346) from Chintan points and confimed that no event has reserved names.

I keep getting the error code 13 - which means *Event name is reserved*, according to the [Analytics Error Codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/errors).

Any ideas of what might be happening? Anybody facing the same issue?

Here's how the error is shown at DebugView:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Adding a piece of the log, as requested:

[image: A piece of the Logcat log]

Comment: can you please provide some log from the debug log, especially those errors after the screen view events? Thanks

Comment: @adbitx just added a piece of the log. I suppose the interesting part here is the error in red, where it says "Name is reserved", but I'm pretty sure I am not using any of the Firebase reserved names.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have GTM SDK by any chance?

Comment: @adbitx yes, it's imported in my app gradle file.

Comment: As Dan stated below, do you log any event with the name "screen_view" too?

Comment: @adbitx nope, I'm only using the `setCurrentScreen()` method, which is the default method for `screen_view` logging. None of my custom events gave "screen_view" in their names.

Comment: Hey @sednanre,  I'm facing the same issue on my side can you suggest me a better solution to solve the regular calling on screen_view and user engagement.

Comment: @MohitLakhanpal still haven't found an answer :/ We ended up using Amplitude to log all events we needed (both screen visualisation and button clicks for example). Took more work once I had to manually tag every event in every Activity/Fragment, but it did work - not sure it's still works like this to these days though.

Answer (score 4):

Can you check to see if you are using your event names prefixed as "*firebase_*", "*google_*" or "*ga_*"?

As per the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event) `**The "firebase_", "google_" and "ga_" prefixes are reserved and should not be used.**`

Comment: None of the events have these prefixes, I have checked the rules at the official documentation. They're all screen names in lowercase starting with alphabetic characters, with a lot less than 36 characters. I am also sending some custom button click events, but they also follow the rules (and these don't even log an error at DebugView).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [API docs for Analytics.Event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event), screen_view is a reserved event name and cannot be used for logging your own custom event.