# Firebase Analytics for React Native Android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

Is there any complete documentation for Firebase Analytics with React Native for Android? There is https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/analytics/android.

But it still not complete and i cannot dig deeper into how to set my custom event, to set my current screen and etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docs are here.
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/analytics/reference/analytics

for example you can send event like this way

```
firebase.analytics().logEvent("Test Event")
```

Comment: i tried, and it give me error "Event name 'Test Event' is invalid" =('

Comment: oh my  bad according to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466666/firebase-analytics-event-logging-error.

Comment: firebase.analytics().logEvent("Test_Event") try like this

Comment: then where will my "Test_Event" appear on the Firebase Analytics? because i couldn't see it

Comment: its take time but you can use debugview. please read this. https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/174

Comment: Now everything appear! Thank you for your advice on this.